# Compactness implies subsequence converges to a point?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a compact set $K$ in a region $\Omega.$ We have that for every $l \geq 0,$ there exists points $z_l \in K, w_l \in \Omega^C$ such that $|z_l - w_l| < 1/l.$ So apparently by the compactness of $K$ there exists a subsequence of $\{z_l\}$ that converges to a point $z \in K.$ Why is this? I get that since $K$ is compact it is closed meaning that it has all its limit points. But the $\{z_l\}$ could be all over the region of $K.$ Why should they be limiting to any one point?

Comment: In Euclidean space, this is a result of the [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Namely, compact sets are bounded, and bounded sequences have convergent subsequences. We can generalize this to metric spaces relatively painlessly. There are lots of questions on Math.SE about understanding Bolzano-Weierstrass. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74822/confused-by-the-bolzano-weierstrass-theorem) is an example.